# Unity two audio listeners on a scene filtering audio sources

Tags: unity-game-engine, webrtc

I am using the Unity WebRTC plugin (https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/com.unity.webrtc) and I need to send multiple audio tracks. For example, I want to send the Spanish version of the received WebRTC on one track, and send the English version of another received WebRTC on a different track. Currently, I am using the OnAudioFilterRead() method to capture the scene audio, but this method does not allow filtering of mixer groups or similar functionalities. How can I achieve this functionality in Unity?

Thank you.